# How do you dynamically display images in Django

Tags: django

I'm trying to dynamically display Images in Django. this is my details page

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

    {% load staticfiles %}


            {% block header %}
                    <!-- Set your background image for this header on the line below. -->
                <header class="intro-header" style="background-image: url('{% static 'blog/img/about-bg.jpg' %}')">
                    <div class="container">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2 col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
                                <div class="page-heading">
                                    <h1>{{ post.title }}</h1>
                                    <hr class="small">
                                    <span class="subheading">blog detail</span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </header>
            {% endblock %}

    {% block content %}
        <h1>{{ post.title }}</h1>
        <h4>{{ post.body }}</h4>
    {% lorem 5 p random %}
    <hr>

    <div id="disqus_thread"></div>
    <script>
    /**
    * RECOMMENDED CONFIGURATION VARIABLES: EDIT AND UNCOMMENT THE SECTION BELOW TO INSERT DYNAMIC VALUES FROM YOUR PLATFORM OR CMS.
    * LEARN WHY DEFINING THESE VARIABLES IS IMPORTANT: https://disqus.com/admin/universalcode/#configuration-variables
    */
    /*
    var disqus_config = function () {
    this.page.url = PAGE_URL; // Replace PAGE_URL with your page's canonical URL variable
    this.page.identifier = PAGE_IDENTIFIER; // Replace PAGE_IDENTIFIER with your page's unique identifier variable
    };
    */
    (function() { // DON'T EDIT BELOW THIS LINE
    var d = document, s = d.createElement('script');

    s.src = '//eights.disqus.com/embed.js';

    s.setAttribute('data-timestamp', +new Date());
    (d.head || d.body).appendChild(s);
    })();
    </script>
    <noscript>Please enable JavaScript to view the
        <a href="https://disqus.com/?ref_noscript" rel="nofollow">comments powered by Disqus.</a>
    </noscript>
    <script id="dsq-count-scr" src="//eights.disqus.com/count.js" async></script>
    {% endblock %}
```

So far I tried storing these approaches. I tried storing this in the database

```
 {% static 'blog/img/about-bg.jpg' %}

 and called it like this
 style="background-image: url('{{ post.title }}')"
```

that didn't work. Then I tried storing it in the database like this

```
'blog/img/about-bg.jpg'
```

and calling it like this

```
style="background-image: url('{% static '{{ post.title }}' %}')
```

then I ried storing it like this in the database

```
static/blog/img/about-bg.jpg
```

and calling it like this

```
style="background-image: url('{{ post.title }}')"
```

I've also tried defining it in the views.py

```
pic = "path/pic.img"
context = {
   "pic": pic
context and calling it
{{pic }}
```

none of these methods work. It's a little different from Laravel. In laravel

```
path/{{ post->title }}
```

would have worked. How can I do this in Django? any and all suggestions are welcome. To be clear I want all my articles to display an image on the index page, then when I click one of them, I am taken to the details page that image for that particular article is displayed

Comment: If you check the page source, are you able to see the image? Or it gives you 404?

Comment: the page is fine just no image

Comment: did your run collectstatic ?

Comment: No. I'm working locally. And I'm using other static files like css, and js and they work fine

Comment: when you say no image, what is the path to that image? if you view source it should show you what is being populated from your server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've figured it out. It's supposed to be stored as

```
/static/blog/img/about-bg.jpg
```

not

```
static/blog/img/about-bg.jpg
```

the forward slash makes it work. in Laravel this does not matter

Answer (score 3):

For adding images dynamically to your webpage using Django :

As we mostly use Jinja for templates,

```
 <img src="{%static 'images/beach.svg' %}" alt="A beach image">
```

We give this kind of commands to access static image files. But for dynamic, we have to change the 'beach.svg' to something like {{dest2.img}} in the above HTML image tag, if my "views.py" function is like :

```
def index(request):
    dest2 = Destination() // Imported class 'Destination()' from models.py .
    dest2.name = 'Beach'
    dest2.img = 'beach.svg' // The image name we need.
    dest2.desc = 'Some beach description'
    dest2.price = 2000

    return render(request, 'index.html', {'dest2' : dest2}) // Passing the object value to html page.
```

If we logically think, the code should be like :

```
<img src="{%static 'images/{{dest2.img}}' %}" alt="A beach image"> // we cannot do this here!!!
```

We cannot use a Jinja code inside another Jinja code. So we add :

```
{% static 'images' as base_url %}
```

at the top of our HTML page. 'images' is the default folder for images and we are calling it as 'base_url' in this HTML page. So we have to use 'base_url' as path and 'dest2.img' as the file name. so the image source will be like :

```
<img src="{{base_url}}/{{dest2.img}}" alt="A beach image">
```

So finally we're done making the dynamic images in Django.!!!

Comment: {% static 'images' as base_url %} is not a good idea. In my case, the following worked:  <img src="{% static 'images' %}/{{ company.chart_filename }}" alt="" title="">, images is a folder inside static folder on AWS S3 bucket.

Answer (score 1):

From you question I understand that by dynamically you mean that you want to upload an image to your site. So it's not just a static image that is always the same like a logo of your page or something.

You have to do this:

In models.py

```
from django.contrib.sites.models import Site
def generate_filename(filename): #it adds the image in a folder with the current year
    ext = filename.split('.')[-1]
    year = datetime.datetime.now().year
    return str(year) + '/' + str(int(time())) + '.' + ext
class PageWithImage(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to=generate_filename, blank=True, null=True)
    site = models.ForeignKey(Site, blank=True, null=True)#this if you want the image linked with your site
```

Then in setting.py you have to add:

```
import os
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'img')
MEDIA_URL = '/img/'
```

Then in the template:

```
<img itemprop="image" src="http://{{ object.site }}{{ object.image.url }}">
```

And don't forget to add the image field to admin.py

Answer (score 0):

First, you cannot use {% static 'blablabla' %} in CSS files.

Second, use this code:

```
style="background: url(/static/blog/img/about-bg.jpg) no-repeat"
```

Third, if you will be working with images from models in the future then your code should be:

```
style="background: url(/{{ your_object.your_img_field }}) no-repeat"
```

Comment: Thanks. I followed a tutorial from youtube and that's how he did it. And the IDE was complaining. What you said makes sense

Comment: You are welcome :-). Btw. I would be grateful for marking this answer as helpful. I just need to hit 50 pts of reputation for ability to comment quesions :-P